# Delete Query by joining multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Table T1 with Column C1,C2 and Table T2 with Column C3,C4,C5. I would like delete records from T1 where C1 = C3 AND C2 = C4 and C5 = '123'. What will be the query I tried following

```
DELETE FROM T1 WHERE (C1,C2) = SELECT (C3,C4) FROM T2 WHERE C5 = '123'
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no `WHERE (x,y) = (a,b)` syntax in SQL Server, sorry. This is how you perform a delete, based on a join, regardless of how many columns are involved in the join:

```
DELETE t1 
  FROM t1
  INNER JOIN t2
  ON t1.c1 = t2.c3
  AND t1.c2 = t2.c4
  WHERE t2.c5 = '123';
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using `exists`:

```
DELETE FROM T1
    WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE C5 = '123' and t2.c3 = t1.c1 and t2.c4 = t1.c2) )
```

In general, using `exists` is better than using `in` with a subquery because NULLs can cause the latter to do behavior in strange ways.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server supports an extra FROM clause in the DELETE statement.

```
DELETE FROM T1
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2
  ON T1.c1 = T2.c3
  AND T1.c2 = T2.c4
  WHERE c5 = '123';
```